# TypeError when digesting Google Maps API

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API in a Sinatra app. I get a TypeError (can't convert String into Integer) whenever I look up an address.

Take a look at my code and let me know what you think the problem is.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'


get '/' do
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  find_location(params[:location]) 
end

def find_location(address)
  url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + CGI.escape(address) + "&sensor=false"
  resp = open(url).read
  parsed_resp = JSON.parse(resp)
  lat = parsed_resp['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']
  lng = parsed_resp['results']['geometry']['location']['lng']
  lat + " " + lng
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsed_resp['results']` is an array, so your code should look like:

```
def find_location(address)
  url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + CGI.escape(address) + "&sensor=false"
  resp = open(url).read
  parsed_resp = JSON.parse(resp)
  unless parsed_resp['results'].empty?
    lat = parsed_resp['results'].first['geometry']['location']['lat'].to_s
    lng = parsed_resp['results'].first['geometry']['location']['lng'].to_s
    lat + " " + lng
  end
end
```